# Booting from an existing harddrive

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hard-drive

I have bought a used MacBook Pro from 2009, but it did not include any installation DVD or hard drive, and I don't have another Mac. I have tried putting a linux SSD in, but that resulted in the disk not found error screen (same as without any drive).

I am trying to get hold of a macOS installer (how do I do that, actually?), but in the meantime I would like to test my device (i bought it broken, so I want to know if my repairs were successful). Can I boot from an existing harddrive?

Comment: Depends on a **lot** of things. OS version, what it was installed on originally, etc. But it is worth a try as it might just work.

Comment: @SteveChambers ok thank you. Do i need a special bootloader? It did not recognize the grub loader from my linux drive. or does this only work if i find a macos ssd/hdd?

Comment: My comment assumed a macOS bootable SSD/HD

Comment: @SteveChambers Okay. What can I do if I do not have a macOS bootable drive?

Comment: Do you have any other computers that can be used to create installation media?  Can you burn a DL DVD? Does the Mac have an optical drive? What operating system do you want to run? The newest macOS that can be installed on that model is El Capitan (OS X 10.11).

Comment: @DavidAnderson Yes, it has an optical drive and I have other computers, but I do not have another Mac. El Capitan is fine for me, I just want it to boot for now.

Comment: There are Windows utilities that will let you "install" a macOS bootable installer to a USB key. I've never used any but I gather they are out there. I found some options for doing so. Just do a search: create macos installer on windows

Comment: You should try booting linux on it.  Ubuntu has an active Mac community. You should ask over their how to install Ubuntu on your machine.